# How Read Write Functions work in File Handling OOP C++

Tags: c++, oop, file-handling

I'm working on File Handling with OOP and have come to know about little built-in functions `write()` & `read()`But I don't know why it required casting. I also tried casting into `int*` instead of `char*` then casting not works. I tried googling but unable to find good tutorials or article.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
class Person{
    private:
        int age;
        char name[15];
        public:
            void getData()
            {
                cout<<"Enter the name of person:";
                cin>>name;
                cout<<"Enter the age of person:";
                cin>>age;
            }
                void showData()
            {
                cout<<"\nName  is:"<<name;
                cout<<"\nAge is:"<<age;
            }
};
int main()
{
    Person p;
    p.getData();
    ofstream outfile("Person.txt");
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), sizeof(p)); // how this works?
    ifstream infile("Person.txt");
    infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&p), sizeof(p)); // how this works?
    p.showData();
    return 0;
 }
```

Can you tell me why Casting required? and why sizeof operator?

Comment: You need to cast to `char*` because these functions are declared to take a parameter of type `char*` (and not `int*` or `Person*`). The second parameter is the number of bytes to write or read - presumably, you want to write or read precisely as many bytes as it takes to represent object `p`, which is handily computed by the expression `sizeof(p)`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik any logic behind just `char*`?

Comment: What more would you expect? These are low level functions, reading and writing blocks of bytes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ok what is the best to read and write data in file handling?

Comment: That rather depends on the nature of said "data", and on how you plan to "handle" it.